# using directives breaks ng-view in angular, how to?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, layout, angularjs-directive

i have a index.html:

```
<body ng-app="app">
    <topmenu></topmenu>
    <div ng-view=""></div>
```

then inside a `views` folder i have `main.html` and `topmenu.html`

there is a route:

```
.when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
})
```

and a directive

```
var App = angular.module('app', []);

App.directive('topmenu', function () {
    return {
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'views/topmenu.html'
    };
});
```

the problem is when i include the `directive.js` file and place the `<topmenu></topmenu>` tag the `main.html` doesn't load no more

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your directive file you don't need to initialize a variable with your module and dependencies a second time. So this:

```
var App = angular.module('app', []);
```

should be removed from that file.

Answer (score 1):

in directive.js

remove this, it will create a new angular module with name 'app'

```
var App = angular.module('app', []);
```

if you want get module from angular you can do

```
var App2 = angular.module('app');
console.log(App === App2) // true
```

and make sure you already created your 'app' module before you load directive.js,

for example, if you have 2 JS file

```
<script src="index.js"/>
<script src="directive.js"/>
```

in index.js do

```
var App = angular.module('app', []);
```